# Can toluene be used as a solvent for nucleophilic substitution?

Tags: organic-chemistry, solvents

This is a continuation to a previous question of mine regarding a change to a one-pot procedure for the preparation of Wellbutrin that I performed in college last semester. Could toluene have been used as the extraction solvent for the a-bromoketone and for the nucleophilic substitution? The procedure we were given used DCM and then removed it under vacuum for a solvent switch to NMP. Also, what was the reason for this? Could a mixture of NMP and DCM have been used?

Previous question: [Suggestions for solvents capable of efficiently performing alpha-bromination and nucleophilic substitutions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49982/suggestions-for-solvents-capable-of-efficiently-performing-alpha-bromination-and/49997#49997)

Comment: Please provide a link to your previous question.

Comment: I added the link in an edit.